# Looping with Promises in JS returning only last result

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, promise, counter

If promise is inside `for` loop and in function located in `then` construct we want to print out current counter, it will 5-times print out last counter value.
What should be done to print sequence from 0 to 4?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>test</th>
        </tr>
    </table> 
    
    <script>
    
    var $row = $('tr')
    for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
     $("<tr><th>test</th></tr>").insertAfter($row).promise().then(() => print(k));
    }
    
    function print(counter){
        setTimeout(() => console.log(counter), 1000);
    }
    
    </script>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why `.promise()`? There's no need for that.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was in usage of `let` keyword instead of `var`. The main difference is the scope difference, while `let` can be only available inside the scope it's declared, like in for loop, `var` can be accessed outside the loop for example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
    </tr>
</table> 

<script>

let $row = $('tr')
for (let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
 $("<tr><th>test</th></tr>").insertAfter($row).promise().then(() => print(k));
}

function print(counter){
    setTimeout(() => console.log(counter), 1000);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```